# SMB Fileshares break every morning

Tags: 18.04, server, samba

First: I'm still quite new to Linux but I've been thrust in to a position at a company where I've inherited someone else's Ubuntu 18.04.04 server (which serves as everything from DHCP, to DNS, to AD-DC for LDAP and SMB File Share).

Over the weekend I did some simple package upgrades via apt and basically got the server up to 18.04.06. Since then, every morning when I come in to the office, the file shares are broken. A full restart of the server resolves the issue, but I'm GUESSING that perhaps something in the 'cron.daily' routine (which, according to crontab, runs at 6:25 every morning) is causing it to break.

The only thing that appears to be related to SAMBA in /etc/cron.daily is a script simply named "samba" which includes the comments:

```
# cron script to save a backup copy of /etc/samba/smbpasswd in /var/backups.
#
# Written by Eloy A. Paris <peloy@debian.org> for the Debian project.
```

So I'm sure this is something everyone has seen before and I don't think it is causing my issue.

If I check within the /var/log/samba.log file there are some errors, but I believe they are red herrings because the server is currently working fine despite the errors.

Some of them include:

```
ubuntu cifs vfs ioctl error in smb2_get_dfs_refer rc=-5
```

```
../librpc/rpc/dcerpc_util.c:264(dcerpc_pull_auth_trailer)
  ../librpc/rpc/dcerpc_util.c:264: ERROR: pad length mismatch. Calculated 44  got 0
```

and

```
../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Again, despite saying "access denied," the shares are working just fine.

Lastly, during boot up, I do see a message saying:

```
winbindd failed to start exit-code
```

But, again... it works after a fresh reboot, so I'm hesitant to think Winbind is the root of my problem?

I'm new at a lot of this and I've spent the last few months learning what I can -- but this has been sort of placed on my shoulders, so I genuinely hope that the "Linux Community" I have heard so much about for decades can come to my rescue! Please tell me anything to check and I'll do what I can! Thanks, everyone!

Comment: For the record, I was never able to specifically resolve precisely THIS issue, but a full-blown release upgrade to 20.04.4 along with all of the required packages has fixed it.